# Change narrow string encoding or missing std::filesystem::path::imbue

Tags: c++, utf-8, filepath, c++17, boost-filesystem

I'm on Windows and I'm constructing `std::filesystem::path` from `std::string`. According to constructor reference (emphasis mine):

> If the source character type is `char`, the encoding of the source is assumed to be the **native narrow encoding** (so no conversion takes place on POSIX systems)

If I understand correctly, this means string content will be treated as encoded in ANSI under Windows. To treat it as encoded in UTF-8, I need to use `std::filesystem::u8path()` function. See the demo: http://rextester.com/PXRH65151

I want constructor of `path` to treat contents of narrow string as UTF-8 encoded. For `boost::filesystem::path` I could use `imbue()` method to do this:

```
boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>()));
```

However, I do not see such method in `std::filesystem::path`. Is there a way to achieve this behavior for `std::filesystem::path`? Or do I need to spit `u8path` all over the place?

Comment: Why are you using ANSI strings in a Unicode OS? Windows uses *Unicode* since day one of Windows NT back in 1993 (I think). You should be using `u16string` or `wstring` for pre-C++11 compilers, if there are any left

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't. We have `UNICODE` defined in all our solutions. What do you mean by "using ANSI"? How am using it my demo?

Comment: `native narrow encoding` means the ASCII code page used by the system's locale, what appears in `Regional Settings` as `Language for non-Unicode programs`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's right, that's what I believe is called ANSI. And we cannot control this settings on computers of our users.

Comment: in C++ `string` and `char` are the single-byte types. Unicode types are multi-byte. UTF16 characters are `char16_t` and the equivalent strings `u16string`. Before C++11 `UNICODE` meant that `wchar` was used wherever teh `_TCHAR` macro appeared. By explicitly using `char` and `string` you are using the single-byte (ASCII/ANSII) types

Comment: Just *don't* do that. Do what all programs in Windows do since 1993 - use the Unicode types.

Comment: It is very convenient to treat std::string as UTF-8 encoded and it is already done in many places. We cannot simply revise all of them. I don't even think it is necessary, because UTF-8 is so easy and widely accepted. Do you have any suggestions on what type to use for UTF-8 encoded strings?

Comment: What you describe holds for Linux and Unix *now*, for US/UK locales. Windows NT went all Unicode though back in the 1990s targeting an international audience, for whom UTF8 would consume *more* space than UTF16. This also avoided the common problem of mixing up UTF8 with localized text.

Comment: @Mikhail: Is there something wrong with using `u8path` when you need to create a path from a UTF-8 string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so how do you suggest writing cross-platform code? Using UTF-16? We are using UTF-8 for this purpose, and I thought this is right.

Comment: Perhaps you can use UTF8 instead of the native UTF16 but you may run into problems. For example,  NTFS supports Unicode paths. You can only get these when you call the Unicode version of Win32 functions (ending with W). I think that only the Unicode versions of the standard library functions call these, although I haven't tested this in a while

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes. We need to insert it everywhere, while it seems very natural to assume that path treats narrow strings as UTF-8 encoded by default, how it works now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The whole point of `filesystem` is that we don't have to do platform-specific coding like that. If you want to use UTF-8 everywhere (and you should), you can.

Comment: @Mikhail: You need to insert `path` everyone as it currently stands. So while you're doing that, why not use `u8path` when you're creating paths from UTF-8 strings?

Comment: @NicolBolas because we already have `fs::path` everywhere, and we wanted just to change `fs` from `boost::filesystem` to `std::filesystem` with the dawn of C++17.

Comment: @NicolBolas just noticed that [path uses wchar_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) on Windows, so issue could be how to convert one Unicode encoding to another.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem is to fully alias the `std::filesystem` to a different namespace named `std::u8filesystem` with classes and methods that treat `std::string` as UTF-8 encoded. Classes inherit their corresponding in `std::filesystem` with same name, without adding any field or virtual method to offer full API/ABI interoperability. Full proof of concept code [here](https://github.com/ceztko/u8filesystem), tested only on Windows so far and far to be complete. The following snippet shows the core working of the helper:

```
std::wstring U8ToW(const std::string &string);

namespace std
{
    namespace u8filesystem
    {

    #ifdef WIN32
        class path : public filesystem::path
        {
        public:
            path(const std::string &string)
                : fs::path(U8ToW(path))
            {
            }

            inline std::string string() const
            {
                return filesystem::path::u8string();
            }
        }
    #else
        using namespace filesystem;
    #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of performance, `path` does not have a global way to define locale conversions. Since C++ pre-20 does not have a specific type for UTF-8 strings, the system assumes any `char` strings are narrow character strings. So if you want to use UTF-8 strings, you have to spell it out explicitly, either by providing an appropriate conversion locale to the constructor or by using `u8path`.

C++20 gave us `char8_t`, which is always presumed to be UTF-8. So if you consistently use `char8_t`-based strings (like `std::u8string`), `path`'s implicit conversion will pick up on it and work appropriately.

Comment: This sounds very unfortunate! Is there a chance to change the standard?

Comment: @Mikhail it took us 24 years to get UTF16 and UTF32 strings. Have patience

Comment: @Mikhail: No, and that's a good thing. The only way to do what you're talking about is to either assume `char` is UTF-8 (which is an incorrect assumption) or to make everyone's code needlessly slower by using some global locale stuff.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: We have UTF-8 strings. We simply don't have a distinct *type* for them.

Comment: @NicolBolas don't see how being unable to apply "UTF-8 everywhere" to my C++ code is a good thing.

Comment: @Mikhail: You can apply that. You simply can't use the `path` constructor to do so. And it's a benefit because it means everyone else's code isn't slowed down by it.

Comment: @NicolBolas wait, `path` [uses `wchar_t` on Windows](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm aware of that. It uses UTF-16 encoding, stored as a `wchar_t` string. But that's its internal encoding. The point of `path` is that you shouldn't *care* what the internal encoding is; you provide a path string in whatever encoding works for you, and you're done. Other APIs that have to interface directly with a filesystem can extract the string in whatever encoding that API uses.

Comment: @NicolBolas one can get used to use `u8path` by default but the problem is the damn `std::string` automatic conversion to `fs::path`. If one stores utf-8 in std::string, which indeed is good, every free function calls like `fs::exists(std::string(filepath))` or `fs::remove(std::string(filepath))` are potentially wrong.

Comment: @ceztko: But those are easy cases to fix: `exists(std::fs::path(filepath))` and so forth. The hard cases are when you *already* have a `std::string` in a variable and want to insert it. You have to know that the API takes a `path`. But there's nothing to be done for that; so long as C++ lacks a specific type for a UTF-8 string, you have to provide some way to differentiate them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Uh? Are you sure you didn't mean `exists(std::fs::u8path(filepath))`? Because as said there's already an (unfortunate) automatic conversion from `std::string` to `fs::path`

Comment: @ceztko: Fair enough. But my overall point was that, since you have to do an explicit conversion *anyway*, you may as well use the *right* explicit conversion. The hard part is when you don't need to use an explicit conversion at all.